# Fatorial não está sendo calculado

Tags: c, matemática

> Faça um programa para ler uma matriz A do tipo vetor com 15 elementos. Construir uma matriz B de
>   mesmo tipo, sendo que cada elemento da matriz B seja o fatorial do elemento correspondente da matriz A .
>   Apresentar as matrizes A e B.

Tentei fazer gente mas algo ta errado e não consigo ver o que é, se alguém puder apontar o erro eu agradeço e desde já valeu pela ajuda...

```
int matriza[5], matrizb[5], matrizc[5], indice, cont = 0, soma = 0;

for(indice = 1; indice <= 5; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n digite um valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&matriza[indice]);
    }

cont = matriza[indice];

for(soma = 1; cont >= 1; cont = cont - 1)
    {
        soma = soma * cont;

        matrizb[indice] = soma;         
    }

for(indice = 1; indice <= 5; indice++)
    {
        printf("\n O valor do vetor B e: %d \n", matrizb[indice]);
    }
```

Comment: Você precisa calcular o fatorial de cada valor do vetor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solução sem usar recursão (que pragmaticamente nem é solução para tudo) já que você não deve entender o que é isto ainda:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int matriza[5], matrizb[5], indice, cont, soma;
    for (indice = 0; indice < 5; indice++) {
        printf("\n digite um valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&matriza[indice]);
        for (soma = 1, cont = matriza[indice]; cont > 1; cont--) soma *= cont;
        matrizb[indice] = soma;
    }
    for (indice = 0; indice < 5; indice++) printf("\n O valor do vetor B e: %d \n", matrizb[indice]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/doMJ1C). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xioutzdq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Factorial.c).

Note que estou trabalhando com os índices do vetor de 0 à 4 ao invés de 1 à 5, como no código original que vai acabar corrompendo a memória.

A não ser que ia fazer algo mais tinha variável sobrando.

Você não está fazendo o laço que calcula o fatorial no lugar certo. Tem que fazer ele com cada número entrado e não apenas uma vez (a não ser que todo o o código inicial estiver errado e você queria calcular o fatorial de apenas um número. Aí não precisaria dos vetores.

Note que eu reinicio o valor de soma todas as vezes que vai começar um novo cálculo de fatorial, caso contrário ele acumularia o fatorial calculado anteriormente.

Tem outras pequenas melhorias que poderia ser feitas mas basicamente é isto.

Comment: Eu vi em algum lugar aqui no site que se deve evitar dizer obrigado, mas poxa bigown tu é o cara sempre me salvando várias vezes, valeu mesmo cara muito obrigado, sei que talvez eu seja penalizado, é por um bom motivo, valeu.

Comment: Evitar não quer dizer que é proibido. É que o mais certo é votar nas respostas (não só nas dadas em sua pergunta) e obviamente aceitar a melhor, o que você faz. Não sei se fez um tudo. O povo também não é tão rígido. Só é penalizado quem apronta coisas "sérias".

Comment: Já ia esquecendo quero agradecer a todas as respostas, pois cada um contribui para melhor o meu e o conhecimento de outros que posam ver esta página, espero que um dia eu também possa estar ajudando novos usuários aqui no site.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar uma [função recursiva](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/O-que-sao-e-como-usar-funcoes-recursivas-em-linguagem-C.html) para resolver este tipo de problema. Por exemplo (veja os comentários):

```
int fatorial(int n)
{
   // caso n seja menor ou igual a 1, retorna 1, 
   // ao contrário multiplica n pelo retorno da chamada da própria função
   // passando n - 1. Portanto, para fatorial(5) = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
   return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fatorial(n - 1);
}
```

No seu exemplo, sempre comece a ler seu vetor com o indice `0`. Seu exemplo, pode ser algo do tipo assim:

```
int matriza[5], matrizb[5], matrizc[5];

for(indice = 0; indice <= 5; indice++)
{
   // le o valor
   printf("\n digite um valor: ");
   scanf("%d",&matriza[indice]);

   // chama a função fatorial e passa o valor da matriza lido anteriormente.
   matrizb[indice] = fatorial(matriza[indice]);
}

for(indice = 0; indice <= 5; indice++)
{
   printf("\n O valor do vetor B e: %d \n", matrizb[indice]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao sair do primeiro for o valor da variável "indice" é 6, e ocorrerá um erro nesse ponto, já que a matriz não tem essa posição. Seria interessante ter o enunciado do seu problema pra termos uma ideia do que esperar da solução.